# Qt5: как понять на каком из lineEdit стоит фокус

Tags: c++, qt5

На форме есть 2 `lineEdit'a`. Есть на форме куча кнопок а-ля цифровая клавиатура (делаю десктоп-приложение с адаптацией под тачскрины). Нужно с этой цифровой клавиатуры вводить данные в тот `lineEdit`, в котором стоит фокус. 
[image: То что нужно сделать]
Как можно объяснить кнопка QPushButton в каком из `lineEdito'в` сейчас находится фокус?

**UPD:**

По совету @magrif сделал следующее:

*mainwindow.h*

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
QObject * m_focused;

void digiKey(QLineEdit *l);
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
m_focused = nullptr;
/*...*/
ui->lineEdit_oPrice->installEventFilter(this);
ui->lineEdit_oAmount->installEventFilter(this);
connect(ui->pushButton_0, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {
    if(m_focused != nullptr) {
        QLineEdit* l = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(m_focused);
        //do something
        digiKey(l);
    }
});    
}

void MainWindow::digiKey(QLineEdit * l)
{
    QPushButton *button = (QPushButton *)sender();
    double Price;
        qDebug() << "isPrice now";
        Price = (l->text() + button->text()).toDouble();
        l->setText(QString::number(Price));
}
```

В конечном счёте, при нажатии на связанную кнопку, программа падает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
if(ui->lineEdit1->hasFocus()) {
    //some work
} else 
if(ui->lineEdit2->hasFocus()) {
    //some work
}
```

**Через события**

В `MainWindow` (или какой там класс для агрегации lineedit'ов) объявить член `QObject* m_focused;`. Переопределить виртуальную член-функцию `eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)` таким образом:

```
bool
MainWindow::
eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn) {
        m_focused = watched;
    }
    return false;
}
```

И в конструкторе установить этот фильтр только на lineEdit'ы, а `m_focused` определить как `nullptr`:

```
ui->lineEdit1->installEventFilter(this);
ui->lineEdit2->installEventFilter(this);
```

Теперь при получении фокуса указатель на текущий lineEdit сохраняется в `m_focused`. Далее работать как угодно с этим объектом по типу:

```
connect(ui->key_X, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {
    if(m_focused != nullptr) {
        QLineEdit* l = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(m_focused);
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: А есть вариант с получением объекта на котором находится фокус, чтобы потом к этому объекту подтащить код? В случае с if то, что я хочу сделать - не работает... 
В частности я сделал так:

`if(ui->lineEdit_oPrice->hasFocus()) {
                numbers = (ui->lineEdit_oPrice->text() + button->text()).toDouble();
                ui->lineEdit_oPrice->setText(QString::number(numbers));
            } `
через второй if обрабатывается второй lineEdit. в итоге клавиатура не работает.

Comment: К слову данный метод не работает только потому, что при нажатии на кнопку, кнопка, судя по всему, перехватывает фокус.

Comment: Сделал так, как вы сказали. В итоге программа падает. В do something прописал `digiKeys(QLineEdit *l) ` в который принимаю то, что создано в соединении. Там, я по l пытаюсь вызывать `l->text();` и `l->setText();`
на всякий случай добавлю описание того, что мне нужно вообще сделать, дабы было яснее, вдруг я чего-то не понимаю в силу того, что работаю с Qt впервые.

Comment: `QPushButton *button = (QPushButton *)sender();` в случае лямбда-выражений не используется, только при старом синтаксисе сигналов-слотов. Надо непосредственно вызывать `ui->button->text()`. Поэтому и падает.

Comment: Почитайте доку про `QSignalMapper` для обработки похожих запросов, прям то что нужно.

Comment: Отлично. Всё сработало. Вопрос, как говорится, до кучи: как можно сказать программе, что я якобы нажал на какую-либо клавишу на клавиатуре(т.е. послать программе сигнал нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре)? Вроде `SendInput` за это отвечает, да?

Comment: `void QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)` переопределить и ловить в нем все нажатия клавиатуры. Типы клавиш находятся в `e->key()`, модификаторы (shift, ctrl) в `e->modifiers()`

Comment: Нет. Там суть была именно не в отлове нажатий с клавиатуры, а наоборот в имитации нажатий с клавиатуры. Идея была такова, чтобы не мучиться с проверками и оставить всё на совесть валидатора. Но погуглив ещё с полчасика по этому вопросу, я вычитал на англоязычном стеке то, что это сулит в себе кучу геморроя. Поэтому пожалуй буду юзать `lineEdit.setText('char');` Все вопросы в данном треде исчерпаны.

Comment: auto keySeq = QKeySequence::fromString(QString('7'));
            auto key = keySeq[0];
            QKeyEvent pressEvent = QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, Qt::NoModifier, QKeySequence(keySeq).toString());
            qApp->sendEvent(m_focused, &pressEvent);